# react testing library render component conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to test if a component renders or not based on a condition using the react testing-library not enzyme.

This is my component source code:

```js
{hasProperties() ? (<TargetComponent />) : null}
```

How can I pass that condition to a test. What I tried is that but obviously without success:

```js
const hasProperties = () => true;
const renderOrNOt = hasProperties() ? (<TargetComponent />) : null;
const { container } = render(renderOrNOt);
expect(container.querySelector('label')).not.toBeNull();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in a function that returns JSX:

```
const hasProperties = () => true;
const RenderOrNOt = () => hasProperties() ? (<TargetComponent />) : null; // Use a function 
const { container } = render(<RenderOrNOt/>);
expect(container.querySelector('label')).not.toBeNull();
```

Altho the best way would be to render the container component for your conditional rendering and check if `TargetComponent` is in the DOM.